# Check rows for same entries in neighbouring columns

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I need a select command to do the following:

I have a table like this

```
ID | col1 | col2 | ...
23 | AAA  |  BBB | ...
23 | BBB  |  AAA | ...
59 | asf  |  567 | ...
02 | XXX  |  ZZZ | ...
02 | YYY  |  XXX | ...
```

There are sometimes 2 rows with the same ID. Now I want to select this ones, which have also the same diametrical neighbouring entries in two specific columns (here col1, col2) like the first two rows at the example. And by analogy this ones, which have the same ID but different entries (see last two rows) .

As a result for the example I want to have two tables:

```
ID | col1 | col2 | ...
23 | AAA  |  BBB | ...
23 | BBB  |  AAA | ...
```

and

```
ID | col1 | col2 | ...
02 | XXX  |  ZZZ | ...
02 | YYY  |  XXX | ...
```

I tried with GROUP BY having count but failed big

Comment: Do you want to turn one table into two new tables? Or do you want a SELECT query that will give you two result sets that you illustrate?

Comment: yes, i want a simple select, sorry for misleading

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is a self-join of your table, using criteria that do three things:

1. Match the id numbers
2. Include the col1/col2 neighbor joins you want
3. Exclude joins of individual rows to themselves.

This query does it.

```
SELECT a.id, a.col1, a.col2
  FROM tbl AS a
  JOIN tbl AS b ON 
      (     a.id=b.id
        AND (a.col1 =  b.col2 OR  a.col2 = b.col1)
        AND (a.col1 != b.col1 AND a.col2 != b.col2)
      )
```

Here's a fiddle.  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3cd08/2/0

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT t0.*
  FROM test t0
  JOIN test t1 ON ((t0.ID=t1.ID) AND
                   (t0.col1=t1.col2 AND t0.col2=t1.col1));

+----+------+------+
| ID | col1 | col2 |
+----+------+------+
| 23 | BBB  | AAA  |
| 23 | AAA  | BBB  |
+----+------+------+

SELECT t0.*
  FROM test t0
  JOIN test t1 ON (NOT (t0.col1=t1.col1 AND t0.col2=t1.col2) AND 
                   (t0.ID=t1.ID) AND 
                   (t0.col1<>t1.col2 OR t0.col2<>t1.col1));
+----+------+------+
| ID | col1 | col2 |
+----+------+------+
|  2 | YYY  | XXX  |
|  2 | XXX  | ZZZ  |
+----+------+------+
```